# How do I upgrade my system to nixos-unstable?

Tags: nixos

How do I make sure that all packages I install on my system nixos installation (i.e. packages listed in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, which I install using `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`) are using the latest (unstable) version of nixos/nixpkgs?

Comment: you can also choose to get individual packages from unstable and the rest from a stable channel

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As explained in [the manual's section on upgrading](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-upgrading), if you issue the following command as root:

```
# nix-channel --list
```

you will most likely see something like the following (if you were following the 16.09 branch for instance):

```
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-16.09
```

By issuing the following command (still as root):

```
# nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable nixos
```

you will remove the 16.09 channel and replace it with nixos-unstable.

Now this is not enough yet. To really update your system, you need one last command:

```
# nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade
```

which is going to rebuild your system with your current configuration and updated packages from the channel you switched to.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me. As @sid-kap said, you really need the `sudo`.

Comment: @haffla Twice in my answer I mention that you need to be root.

Comment: update your channel before rebuilding or it won't have any effect `sudo nix-channel --update`

Comment: The `--upgrade` option is meant to perform the `--update` so when using exactly the commands that I indicated, it should work fine.

Comment: I had to run `sudo nix-channel --update` first, otherwise `sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` gives me me an error: `error: reading symbolic link '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos-unstable': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 5):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable
sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

Note that the `sudo` is required: if you don't use `sudo`, it will only affect user-level packages (i.e. things you install using `nix-env -i`), not system-level packages.

Comment: What's the difference between the two channels?

Comment: I think one is for the core Nixos operating system, the other is for the additional software you install.

Comment: nixos is typically package set for NixOS, nixpkgs is package set when you have nix installed as package manager on non NixOS distro. They are built from the same repo. https://hydra.nixos.org/jobset/nixos/release-19.03#tabs-configuration https://hydra.nixos.org/jobset/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-19.03-darwin#tabs-configuration

Comment: There's some more info here about difference between the channels: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/differences-between-nix-channels/13998